# Get stock industry sector

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

im trying to pull the sector for companies from marketwatch`=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/AAPL/company-profile", "table", 5), 2, 2)`
I dont know how to determine what table number to use or how to find the correct column etc.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to get the XPATH of the html element and then use IMPORTXML.

First you need to get the XPATH, easiest way is with Chrome's Inspect feature.

- Right Click on the sector name
- Select Inspect
- Find the line of HTML that is highlighted blue (it doesn't always appear in the middle of the tool)
- Click on the three dots to the left of the line
- Click Copy
- Click full Xpath

[image]

Then go to your sheet and use `IMPORTXML()`

[image]

To go one step further, you can do it for a list of stocks, by building the URL with the companies stock symbol like this:

`"https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"&LOWER(D9)&"/company-profile"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From a ticker (french) :

**Having the full name :** `=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"&MAJUSCULE(A2)&"/company-profile?countrycode=fr&mod=mw_quote_tab";"/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/h4")`

**Having the industry or sector :**
`=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/"&MAJUSCULE(A2)&"/company-profile?countrycode=fr&mod=mw_quote_tab";"/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/span")`